# Javascript: Getting undefined on input box that takes a range from 0 to 10

Tags: javascript, undefined, counter, inputbox

I have two buttons (+ and -) and an input box with a value of 10. The input must take a value from 0 to 10 only and I can't figure out why I'm getting undefined after I reach either 0 or 10 on the input box. I tried using parseInt for the values. But perhaps I'm not doing it on the right place. Would appreciate the help.

```js
var fighterScore1 = document.getElementById("fighterScore1");
fighterScore1.value  = 10;
var fighter1Inc = document.getElementById("fighter1Inc");
var valor = 10;

 fighter1Inc.onclick = function (valor) {
  fighterScore1.value = increaseValue(valor);
 };
 fighter1Dec.onclick = function (valor) {
  fighterScore1.value = decreaseValue(valor.value);
 };
  function decreaseValue() {
  if (valor <= 0 ) {

     } else {
     valor--;
      return valor;
     }
 };
 function increaseValue() {
  if (valor >= 10 ) {
      valor = 10;
     } else {
     valor++;
      valor = valor;
      return valor;
     }
     
 };
```

```html
<div id="rwid1">
   <button id="fighter1Inc">+</button>
   <input type="text" id="fighterScore1" maxlength="10" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
   <button id="fighter1Dec">-</button>
  </div><!--/rwid-->
```

Comment: you are passing arguments into increaseValue but the function itself does not accept arguments ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're only returning inside the condition that it is less than 10 or greater than 0. If you don't return in one condition,there is no return value so you end up assigning `undefined` to a variable. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tny0t4or/) is a fixed JSFiddle. You have to return outside the if statements, and `valor.value` doesn't exist.

```js
var fighterScore1 = document.getElementById("fighterScore1");
fighterScore1.value  = 10;
var fighter1Inc = document.getElementById("fighter1Inc");
var valor = 10;

fighter1Inc.onclick = function (valor) {
 fighterScore1.value = increaseValue();
};

fighter1Dec.onclick = function (valor) {
 fighterScore1.value = decreaseValue();
};

function decreaseValue() {
 if (valor <= 0 ) {
        valor = 0;
 } else {
     valor--;
 }
 return valor;
};

function increaseValue() {
 if (valor >= 10 ) {
     valor = 10;
 } else {
     valor++;
 }
    return valor;
};
```

```html
<div id="rwid1">
 <button id="fighter1Inc">+</button>
 <input type="text" id="fighterScore1" maxlength="10" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
 <button id="fighter1Dec">-</button>
</div><!--/rwid-->
```

A note: you pass arguments into a function that takes none (JS accepts a varying number of arguments, even if you don't specify). Either you remove the call with arguments, or you use an argument and pass it in, using the argument in place of `valor`.

Comment: Great. I see, I was sure I was returning values within the if statements.  Thanks for the explanation. It makes sense to me now.

Comment: No problem! If you need anything else, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually returning any values in your branches for when `valor <= 0` or `valor >= 10`. If you ever forget to return a value in JavaScript, you'll get an *implicit return* at the end of the function with the value `undefined`.

To fix this, just add `return` statements for `valor` at the end of your function, or in each branch of your `if`/`else`.

For example

```
function decreaseValue() {
    if (valor <= 0 ) {
         return 0;
    }
    else {
        return valor - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that not all paths in `incriseValue` and `decreaseValue` return something. It means `return undefined;`. Additionally (to your luck) `incriseValue` and `decreaseValue` don't use arguments and work with global `varlor`. Here is fixed code.

```js
var fighterScore1 = document.getElementById("fighterScore1");
fighterScore1.value = 10;
var fighter1Inc = document.getElementById("fighter1Inc");
var valor = 10;
var fighter1Dec = document.getElementById("fighter1Dec");

fighter1Inc.onclick = function() {
  fighterScore1.value = increaseValue();
};
fighter1Dec.onclick = function() {
  fighterScore1.value = decreaseValue();
};

function decreaseValue() {
  if (valor > 0)
    valor--;
  return valor;
};

function increaseValue() {
  if (valor < 10)
    valor++;
  return valor;

};
```

```html
<div id="rwid1">
  <button id="fighter1Inc">+</button>
  <input type="text" id="fighterScore1" maxlength="10" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
  <button id="fighter1Dec">-</button>
</div>
<!--/rwid-->
```